# Chatter Post and Tag user from Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, connect-api

I'm trying to do a chatter post and tag a user on a record from Apex Trigger.

I tried the following approach,per https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2013/10/03/chatter-for-apex-code-examples/

```
Id userId = userinfo.getUserId();
Id userToMentionId = userinfo.getUserId();
string postText = 'test post';

ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

// add some text before the mention
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'Hey ';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

// add the mention
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegment = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
mentionSegment.id = userToMentionId;
messageInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegment);

// add the text that was passed
textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = postText;
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
input.body = messageInput;

// post it
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.UserProfile, userId, input, null);
```

It says that that the method is removed, Error below,

```
Method was removed after version 31.0: postFeedItem
```

I tried invoking the Chatter Rest Api for post and tagging user, it worked but I dont want a webservice approach. Please guide

Webservice :

```
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
        
        String url = salesforceHost + '/services/data/v33.0/chatter/feed-elements';
        system.debug('Url generated: '+url);
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sesId);
        
        req.setBody('{"body": {"messageSegments": [{"type": "mention", "id": "' + UserId + '"}, {"type": "text", "text": "' + ' ' + ChatterPostText + '"} ] }, "feedElementType": "FeedItem", "subjectId": "' + RecordId + '", "visibility": "AllUsers"}');
        Http http = new Http();
        
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('Response: '+res.getBody());
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Post Feed Element](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_postFeedElement_1) can be used to post your ConnectApi.FeedItemInput

Comment: SF is notorious for killing links.. can you add relevant code snippets so this answer is still relevant even if the link dies?

Answer (score 6):

You can work with the [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) [ChatterFeeds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods) classes to post directly yourself. Using `postFeedElement(communityId, feedElement)` should be enough to swap in with your original top code (where you create the `ConnectApi.FeedItemInput`) and there's other examples in the doc. They have one for mentions as well which is pasted below (one change to make communityId null if it's not a community):

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

mentionSegmentInput.id = '005RR000000Dme9';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput.text = 'Could you take a look?';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = '0F9RR0000004CPw'; //swap in your record/User Id depending on where this post is supposed to go

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput);
```

Just as a FYI - there's also a [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) repository which can make this less verbose, but unless you have a heavy code use case for posting/working with chatter you might not need it.